# Need to change file content with script but retain original filenames

Tags: bash, sed, awk, filenames

I have several thousands of files with coded weather information in a folder. To every file I need to add a header and footer with control characters. This is not the problem as I have the header and footer in separate files (achieved with the `cat` command in a bash script).

However, the modified files need to retain their original names - this gives me a problem as I only have a very basic scripting knowledge. The reason for keeping them is that these files will be parsed and decoded. The file names contain vital information for how the decoders will process the content.

All the files that are to be decoded are in a separate file, `list_of_files_to_decode.txt`.

A part of the folder content can look like this:

```
a_snvs02wiix170600_c_eswi_20121117062131_76.txt
a_smci40babj170600_c_kwbc_20121117061545_3.txt
a_sath40vtbb170600_c_ekmi_20121117061604_95.txt
a_usxx40mynn70600cca_c_edzw_20121117062020_34.txt
a_siin40dems170600_c_ojam_20121117062020_40.txt
a_smxx40fapr170600rra_c_lowm_20121117062604_67.txt    
list_of_files_to_decode.txt   
start-seq.txt    
stop-seq.txt
```

I have checked the web, and tested some of my own ideas - using `awk` and `sed` - but I can't really find that any suitable way of how I can achieve this in an easy way. So, I would appreciate some help or hints of how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    cat header.txt "$file" footer.txt > newfile && mv newfile "$file"
done < list_of_files_to_decode.txt
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- I simply use concatenation and shell redirection
- `&&` is a shortcut. This is the same as `if condition; then action; fi`

Comment: `+1` added accordingly `;-)`

Comment: It'd fail for file names with backslashes in them and file names that start or end with spaces and there may be other unusual cases. Always write your while read loops as `while IFS= read -r variable` rather than just `while read variable`. IFS= takes care of file names that start or end with spaces, and -r takes care of file names that contain backslashes. It'd still fail for file names containing newlines but there comes a point....

Comment: When you control the input file and the content, it's not required, but post edited accordingly for much more generic re-usable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The only safe way is to rename the original file first

```
mv $file $file.orig
cat header $file.orig footer > $file && rm $file.orig
```

or vice versa create a new file and then overwrite the original

```
cat header $file footer > $file.new && mv -f $file.new $file
```

Comment: That's even more simple than I anticipated. I have tested and it works  fine.
Many thanks.

Comment: Always quote your variables unless you have a very good, explicit reason not to. `mv $file $file.orig` is very different from `mv "$file" "${file}.orig"` and is almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Loopless way with `sed`:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'
sed -i '1 r header.txt
        1 N
        $ r footer.txt' $(<list_of_files_to_decode.txt)
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

---

Notes:

- Set `IFS` to newline only in case there are spaces in filenames
- `r` prints content of file upon reading the next line
- `1 N` prevents first line from getting printed before the content of `header.txt`

  (Details: it reads 2nd line and append to pattern space, triggering `r` to print out the contents of `header.txt`. After that, the pattern space, now consisting of lines 1 and 2, is only printed out at the end of the cycle)
- Of course, backing up and resetting `IFS` might not be necessary if you're using a script.

Comment: Always quote your variables unless you have a very good, explicit reason not to. IFS=$OLDIFS is very different from IFS="$OLDIFS" and is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Wordsplitting does not happen on assignment unless a command substitution is involved.

Comment: It's more than word splitting you need to worry about (see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) but it looks like you're correct and in an assignment it is safe to leave the variable unquoted. Never noticed that before because I always quote my variables unless I have a very specific reason not to. Saves getting surprised at other times.